# Flow to Query Related Contacts and send email

Tags: visual-workflow, recordtriggeredflow

How can I create a record triggered flow that will start when a custom survey object has a negative status.. the flow needs to pull in two contact name fields on the survey object, query those against the contact object (if Sarah smith is the found on the contact then save that email) in order to send an email that the survey was negative. The contact object is not related to surveys so I need to do it through flow just based on a name field (20 or so contacts to query based on this one account). I assume I need to start by filtering by the survey status of negative, get records of contacts related to the specific account name, use a decision to make sure the email isn't blank - but that is where I am stuck on what to do next? Do I filter, do i query, where do I save the emails to send the email alert?

Answer (score 0):

You have to loop through the retrieved Contacts and store their email addresses in a collection variable of type text, then you can use that collection of emails as an input parameter for the Send Email action.

Check this document with the input variables of the "Send Email" action.

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.flow_ref_elements_actions_sendemail.htm&type=5